# Why CustomScrollView is not detecting scrolling

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using CustomScrollView inside Scaffold ,dont't know why it's not detecting Scrolling behaviour.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          // SliverAppBar(floating: true,),
          SliverAppBar(
          
            expandedHeight: 300,
            flexibleSpace:  FlexibleSpaceBar(
              background: Image.asset(
                "assets/image/food.png",
                width: double.maxFinite,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what platform? is it flutter desktop or web?

Comment: flutter Desktop

Comment: add `scrollBehavior: const MaterialScrollBehavior().copyWith(dragDevices: {PointerDeviceKind.mouse},),` to `MaterialApp`

Comment: still not working

Comment: i am using inside GetMaterialApp

Comment: i have no idea what `GetMaterialApp` is

Answer (score 0):

try using SingleChildScrollView()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).